# UK Visitor Visa financial documents

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

My mom wants to apply for a UK visit visa to come visit me in England! My mother is a Moroccan citizen and she is unemployed but she own the house she lives in with my dad and sister, and has £9000 savings in her bank account from self employed jobs she had in the past.

She will be staying at my flat and my dad will be helping her pay for her trip.

I am worried as I've seen so many refusals because of savings unemployed applicants own, and I just wonder if she only must provide the home office with my dad's bank account where he receives his salary every months and ask him to be her sponsor and not mention her savings, or if she should provide information of her savings as well and explain that it comes from jobs she had in the past.

There is no document she can provide to prove that she was working.